# Assigned paragraph value in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, django

Hi I am using django with an internal angularjs in it. however I fail to assign my django variable to angularjs variable. Sorry It is difficult for me to explain it well. This is my code instead

I intarpolate tag from `{{` to `{$`, so angularjs and django wont have any conflict.

`djangoVariable` - this is taken from textarea that contain a lot of text and multiple line paragraph

html file

```
<div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
    <p>{$ description $} </p>
</div>

<script>

app
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.description= {{djangoVariable}};

})

</script>
```

The problem is, the value is not showing.

I hope I explained it well. Thank you in advance

Comment: $scope.description= "{{djangoVariable}}"; should work. You should have " " around the "{{ data }} ", I guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
    <p>{{ description }} </p> //use from angular js
    <p>{% djangoVariable %} </p> // Use from directly views.py
</div>

<script>

app
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.description= "{{djangoVariable}}";

})

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This must be failing because {{djangoVariable}} creates some spaced texts which javascript failed to understand, if you put the variable in "", it should understand. Try this

```
<div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
    <p>{$ description $} </p>
</div>

<script>

app.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.description= "{{djangoVariable}}";

})

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was able to show it however in some cases when the value is a long paragraph with a long on entered line, it would also fail to display